# What could cause these tonal artifacts on each frame of this panorama?

Tags: artifacts, black-and-white, 35mm, light-leaks

I recently used Microsoft Image Composite Editor to stitch this panorama together from scanned negatives.  The film I used was Ilford Delta 100, and the camera is a Nikon FM with a 50mm lens.  Each of the five frames were shot with the camera rotated 90 degrees (roll) on its ball mount (i.e. "Portrait style").

As you can see, the borders between the individual frames of the panorama are clearly distinguishable due to what appears to be tonal artifacts that present in the same part of the frame on each shot.

My question is this:  What could be causing this tonal variation across the frame?

Should I be concerned about light leaking?

[image: full panorama]

*Edit: 
I do not know how these were scanned, though that could be a likely culprit.  I had them developed + scanned commercially.

IIRC I shot these at f/16, 1/160s.

Here is one of the individual unedited frames.  I've scaled it down by 50%.
[image: center frame]

Comment: It might be helpful to also post one of the full scans (the full frame, not full resolution) pre-stitching.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle will do in a couple of hours.

Comment: What exposure method was used? What aperture?

Comment: How were the negatives scanned? (Device? Holder? Backlight? etc.)

Comment: @Michael Clark I just added the f-stop and exposure time (f/16, 1/160) to the post.  I also added that I had these developed + scanned professionally and so I do not have any insights into that.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'exposure method', so if you could give me an example or someplace to look at to learn more about that I can try to give a better response.

Comment: I think these is either overcorrected vignetting in the original shots, or stitching artefacts (from inferior software algorithms)

Comment: @AddisonSchuhardt Exposure method: i.e. manual, aperture priority, etc. It seems you used the same exposure for each frame so that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you use any kind of filter? Specifically a polarizer?

Comment: @Michael Clark Just a UV filter.

Comment: @Aganju Have you ever seen a 50mm lens vignette at f/16?

Comment: @AddisonSchuhardt Do you have an even rudimentary way to scan the negatives yourself? Resolution wouldn't matter. It would be to check and see if the difference from one side of your images to the other is present in the negatives.

Comment: @MichaelClark , my point is that you can _overcorrect_ a non-existent vignette too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all look, for whatever reason, to be ever so slightly brighter on the left than on the right. It is especially noticeable in the sky, but it is also there below the horizon. This seems to have confused the stitching program somehow.

I doubt the source of the variable brightness is a light leak. The difference is way too uniform all the way down your strip of film. Light leaks usually have hot spots.

My best guess is that the scanning process somehow managed to illuminate the one edge of your film strip slightly brighter than the other as it was scanned. Have you inquired with the processing lab that developed your film to see what they might think?

Comment: I will be asking the shop I send these two which lab they use, and talking with them to determine if that might be the culprit.  I'll be scanning these on my own as you suggested to compare.  Thank you for all the help and insights!  Definitely puts me at ease knowing it's likely the scanning that is the issue.  I will continue to investigate.